# WebdriverIO scrape content from x pages

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver-io

So I am working on an API using WebdriverIO to automate some stuff for sites that have no API support. Currently facing an issue with trying to dynamically scrape x number of pages. The scenario is only say 20 items are listed on each page and I can click next to jump to the next, scrape it and repeat until there are no more pages.

The issue; There are not a specific number of pages, at one time it could be 2 and another it could be 12 so I need to do this dynamically.

My problem (I think); Judging from console output I believe the selenium session is being killed before the recursive scraping is finished and that's because it's proceeding to the execute I have there to test things.

My question; How can I recursively scrape those pages without the script continuing and terminating the session before I am finished?

Here is a slightly redacted version of what I have so far. Thanks!

```
...webdriver doing stuff that works...
.then(function() {
  console.log('Entering the initial THIS...');

  function recursive() {
    console.log('This is inside the RECURSIVE Function!');

    client
      .execute(function() {
        return document.title;
      })
      .then(function(ret) {
        console.log('The thing I asked it for is: ' + ret.value);
      })
      .isExisting('#lastPage').then(function(lastPage) {
        console.log(lastPage);

        if (!lastPage) {
          console.log('Its not the last page!');
          client
            .click('//a[text()="Next"]')
            .saveScreenshot('/src/api/debug_images/05.png')

          recursive();
        }
      })
  }

  recursive();
})
.execute(function() {
  var table = document.getElementById("transactionHistoryTable");
  var result = [];

  for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
    result.push({
      date: row.cells[0].innerText,
      details: row.cells[1].innerText,
      debt: row.cells[2].innerText,
      credit: row.cells[3].innerText,
      balance: row.cells[4].innerText
    });
  }

  return result;
})
.then(function(ret) {
  return ret.value;
})
.then(function(ledger) {
  console.log('This should not run yet?');
  res.json({
    status: 'success',
    request: { bsb: bsb, account: account, period: period },
    ledger: ledger.length
  });
})
.end();
```

Comment: I solved a similar problem leveraging generators and promises. In order for webdriverio to keep selenium going, your recursions have to be going in webdriverio as well. For asynchronousl, that would mean generators. But as I just went to look up examples for generators for webdriverio, it has been removed in V4, and everything is now blocking. So if you are in V3, use generators. If you plan to migrate to V4, you may want to rewrite your tests so they don't have to use promises anymore. http://webdriver.io/guide/getstarted/v4.html